# C++ opening a .txt file and creating a new one

Tags: c++, file

So I'm trying to make a program that will open up a text file based on user input (or fail trying), read the contents and create a new text file named after user input and rewrite the contents, but this time with row numbers.

I'm having trouble that I can't pin down on anything specific. My Qt Creator gives no massive errors, but the program seems to halt around line 30 without any error messages.

An online C++ compiler complained about a segmentation problem.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input_file = "";
    cout << "input file: ";
    getline(cin, input_file);

    vector<string> line_vector;

    string output_file = "";
    cout << "output file:";
    getline(cin, output_file);


    ifstream file_object(input_file);
    if ( not file_object )
    {
        cout <<"Error! The file " << input_file <<
               " cannot be opened." << endl;
    } else {
        int row_number = 0;
        string line;
        while (getline(file_object, line) )
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            line_vector[row_number] = line;
            ++row_number;
        }
        file_object.close();

        ofstream output_file;
        output_file.open("");
        for (int i = 0; i>=row_number;++i)
        {
            output_file << i << " " << line_vector[i] << "\n";
        }
        output_file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `output_file.open("");` - Perhaps a file name would be handy

Comment: "*line 30*" are we supposed to guess which line it is? We'd have to assume you copy-pasted the exact code and did not change any lines. Please mark the 30th line in the code to avoid this problem

Comment: When you define a vector like `line_vector`, it starts out *empty*. All indexing into it will be *out of bounds* and lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Please learn how to [*push back*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) elements into a vector.

Answer (score 0):

What the code is doing on this line: `line_vector[row_number] = line` is not actually appending to the vector - which is what you are trying to do -, but instead accessing an element at the index `i` inside the vector, and trying to assign `line` to it.
This would be fine, however, since the vector has 0 size, it is trying to assign `line` to unknown memory. This leads to undefined behaviour, and often, crashes. 
You can do one of two things. 
The first is to use `resize` or `reserve` to reserve the memory for the vector, then assign the variable, like so:

```
while (getline(file_object, line) ) {
    cout << line << endl;
    line_vector.resize(row_number + 1);
    line_vector[row_number] = line;
    ++row_number;
}
```

However, this is pretty pointless, and instead, you should use `push_back`:

```
while (getline(file_object, line) ) {
    cout << line << endl;
    line_vector.push_back(line);
}
```

nullifying the use of `row_number` in that loop.
Oh, and don't use `using namespace std`, it's a bad habit.

Answer (score -1):

"When you define a vector like line_vector, it starts out empty. All indexing into it will be out of bounds and lead to undefined behavior. Please learn how to push back elements into a vector. "

– Some programmer dude

Comment: It would be kind of you to make this into a community-wiki.

Comment: Well, there were no "answers" when there already was that comment so I figured that I should put it up as an answer to take the question off of the unanswered section, but I guess not